# Trying to remove some text from text REGEX

Tags: c#, regex

I have text something like this:

```
 1) chicken burger </br> 2)Chips </br> 3) xyz </br>
```

this Data Save in Web Database m accessing this and show into the winforom  in winform i don't want `</br>` and `1),2),3)` and space replace with `,`.

Comment: </br> save with text in database but when m showing this text on winform so i don't want </br>

Comment: So what have you tried to achieve your goals so far?

Comment: use the [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

Comment: Please remove the "winforms" tag, this question does not have anything to do with winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String temp = "1) chicken burger </br> 2)Chips </br> 3) xyz </br>";
temp  = temp.Replace("</br>",",");
```

use the new temp to output to the winform and use the old one for what you need the  in for.

I would have asked but i can't comment yet

Comment: As strings are immutable in C# - there is no need to use temporary variable. `temp.Replace` itself doesn't change content of `temp` - so that method can be called on original string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) functions. One to remove the tags and the number part and the one to replace two or more spaces inside the resulted string with comma.

```
string str = "1) chicken burger </br> 2)Chips </br> 3) xyz </br>";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"^\d+\)\s*|\s*<[^<>]*>$|\d+\)|<[^<>]*>", "");
string ou = Regex.Replace(result, @"\s{2,}", ",");
Console.WriteLine(ou);
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you want to replace only the `</br>` tag then replace `<[^<>]*>` in the above regex to `</br>`

Output:

```
chicken burger,Chips,xyz
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/pUw3o4)